# Not able to set response status code, without ExpressJs

Tags: node.js

Not able to set response status code(after trying for 2 hours) in node.js 8.9

Tried : `res.statusCode  = 404;` and `res.writeHead(404,{});`
Both didn't work.

Note: NOT using `expressJs`

## Sample Code

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
try{
  res.write('Hie !'); //write a response to the client
  res.statusCode = 404;
  //res.writeHead(404,{});
  res.end(); //end the response
}catch(e){
  console.error(e);
}
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

Note: NOT using `expressJs`

Comment: Can you show more of your code? It's possible you aren't calling these in the right place.

Comment: Can't help you without seeing code for a whole request handler that has this problem. And, pretty annoying that it took you 11 hours after posting to clarify that you're not using Express even though your question is tagged with Express.  I will spend my time help those who are more responsive when answers are posted.  Bye.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `express` if you're not using Express?

Comment: i didn't tagged express, someone else did .. @paul, This piece of code itself is not working..

Comment: @andNn I wrote my comment when all you had was the two statements, now that you're showing the full handler code, I was able to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Sorry Paul,, my bad ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple, the `statusCode` has to be set before you write anything to the response stream, because otherwise it is an implicit 200 code.

Also, you should know that your try...catch block is useless in a callback scenario like that, unless you're doing some form of synchronous code that might fail.

If you update your code to the below, it'll work:

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.statusCode = 404;
  res.write('Hi!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

You could also use ES6 syntax, which some like better for various reasons:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.write('Hi!');

    res.end();

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: superb thanks !! found the issue .. Hie should be changed to Hi ;)

Answer (score -2):

As per [Express V5](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-5.html#res.send.status)

```
res.sendStatus(statusCode)
```

> Express 5 no longer supports the signature res.send(status), where status is a number. Instead, use the res.sendStatus(statusCode) function, which sets the HTTP response header status code and sends the text version of the code: “Not Found”, “Internal Server Error”, and so on.

As per the [Express (Version 4+) docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status):

```
res.status(400);
```